# Не могу загрузит модель на Microsoft SQL Server из фреймворка Prisma

Tags: sql-server

Вроде все делаю согласно инструкции. Прописал DATABASE_URL, но не может соединиться[image: введите сюда описание изображения] с базой, может кто сталкивался. Буду признателен за помощь

PS C:\Users\perek\StudioProjects\untitled2> npx prisma db push
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": SQL Server database

Error: Schema engine error:
Error creating a database connection.